# Dynamic Javascript in Partial Page Postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax, tablesorter

I'm using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jQuery plugin to do some sorting of my tables. The site I'm using this on is programmed in .Net 3.5 and I am using the ASP.NET AJAX and updatepanels to perform my asynchronous page updates.

The problem I'm running into is when using the table sorter, I have some columns that I want to disable sorting on. I have the following javascript code to do so,

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        // Set table sorting in the load event so this takes care of partial page postbacks
        $$("gvRosters").tablesorter({
            sortList: [[0, 0]],
            widgets: ['zebra'],
            8: {
               // disable it by setting the property sorter to false
               sorter: false
            } 
        });
    }
```

The column I want to hide is the 9th column, and everything works  fine. I put this code in the pageLoad function so that it will run on partial postbacks, which it does. The issue is that I have a linkbutton that calls an asynchronous update on the page which changes the visible columns in my table. So the 9th column that I need to hide becomes the 12th column that needs to be hidden. I'm not sure the correct approach to use to rewire the hidden column so that it reads:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        // Set table sorting in the load event so this takes care of partial page postbacks
        $$("gvRosters").tablesorter({
            sortList: [[0, 0]],
            widgets: ['zebra'],
            11: {
               // disable it by setting the property sorter to false
               sorter: false
            } 
        });
    }
```

instead on a partial postback. Basically what I need to do is run this code again on partial postback (which it does already when inside the pageLoad function) but I also need to dynamically change the javascript code that is run in order to disable sorting on the correct column. I appreciate any insight you can provide on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 javascript methods,

1. initial on first page load (which is for 9 cols),
2. next time you modify your cols (makes 12 cols).

Initially call method 1 directly from your javascript code. And on asyn postback from linkbutton you can call the 2nd javascript method using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

Hope this helps.